# Budget doesn't recalculate after deleting last item from data

Tags: javascript, function

So I have this code for a budget app that I'm doing on a javascript course on Udemy. There's a function to delete the item from the data structure, from the UI and to update the budget. It works fine until when I delete the last item from the list i.e the last item on the array, it deletes the item from the data array and from the UI, but don't recalculate the budget.

I tried to look up into my code, and didn't found anything, so that's why I need you, more experienced guys help :)

```js
// BUDGET CONTROLLER
var budgetController = (function() {

  var Expense = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  }

  var Income = function(id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  }

  var calculateTotal = function(type) {
    var sum = 0;

    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur) {
      sum += cur.value;
      data.totals[type] = sum;
    })
  }

  var data = {
    allItems: {
      exp: [],
      inc: []
    },
    totals: {
      exp: 0,
      inc: 0
    },
    budget: 0,
    percentage: -1
  }

  return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val) {
      var newItem, ID;

      // Create a new ID
      if (data.allItems[type].length > 0) {
        ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      // Create a new item object
      if (type === 'exp') {
        newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
      } else if (type === 'inc') {
        newItem = new Income(ID, des, val);
      }

      // Push the created object into the data structure
      data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

      // Return the newItem publicly
      return newItem;
    },
    deleteItem: function(type, id) {
      var ids, index;

      ids = data.allItems[type].map(function(current) {
        return current.id;
      });

      index = ids.indexOf(id);

      if (index !== -1) {
        data.allItems[type].splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    calculateBudget: function() {
      // Calc total income and expenses
      calculateTotal('exp');
      calculateTotal('inc');

      // Calc the budget(income - expenses)
      data.budget = data.totals.inc - data.totals.exp;

      // Calc the percentage of income spent
      if (data.totals.inc > 0) {
        data.percentage = Math.round((data.totals.exp / data.totals.inc) * 100);
      } else {
        data.percentage = -1;
      }
    },
    getBudget: function() {
      return {
        budget: data.budget,
        totalInc: data.totals.inc,
        totalExp: data.totals.exp,
        percentage: data.percentage
      }
    },
    testing: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }

})();



// UI CONTROLLER
var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMStrings = {
    inputType: '.add__type',
    inputDescription: '.add__description',
    inputValue: '.add__value',
    inputBtn: '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer: '.income__list',
    expensesContainer: '.expenses__list',
    budgetLabel: '.budget__value',
    incomeLabel: '.budget__income--value',
    expensesLabel: '.budget__expenses--value',
    percentageLabel: '.budget__expenses--percentage',
    container: '.container'
  }
  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputType).value, // Will be inc or exp
        description: document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputDescription).value,
        value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(DOMStrings.inputValue).value)
      }
    },
    addListItem: function(obj, type) {
      var html, newHtml, element;

      // Create HTML string with placeholder text
      if (type === 'inc') {
        element = DOMStrings.incomeContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      } else if (type === 'exp') {
        element = DOMStrings.expensesContainer;

        html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>'
      }

      // Replace placeholder with actual data
      newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', obj.value);

      // Insert HTML into the DOM
      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
    },
    deleteListItem: function(selectorID) {
      var el = document.getElementById(selectorID);
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    },
    clearFields: function() {
      var fields, fieldsArr;

      fields = document.querySelectorAll(DOMStrings.inputDescription + ', ' + DOMStrings.inputValue);

      fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);

      fieldsArr.forEach(function(current, index, array) {
        current.value = '';
      });

      fieldsArr[0].focus();
    },
    displayBudget: function(obj) {
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.budgetLabel).textContent = obj.budget;
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.incomeLabel).textContent = obj.totalInc;
      document.querySelector(DOMStrings.expensesLabel).textContent = obj.totalExp;

      if (obj.percentage > 0) {
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.percentageLabel).textContent = obj.percentage + '%';
      } else {
        document.querySelector(DOMStrings.percentageLabel).textContent = '---';
      }
    },
    getDOMStrings: function() {
      return DOMStrings;
    }
  }

})();



// GLOBAL APP CONTROLLER
var controller = (function(budgetCtrl, UICtrl) {

  var setupEventListeners = function() {
    var DOM = UICtrl.getDOMStrings();

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener('click', ctrlAddItem);

    document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
        ctrlAddItem();
      }
    });

    document.querySelector(DOM.container).addEventListener('click', ctrlDeleteItem);
  }

  var updateBudget = function() {
    // Calculate budget
    budgetCtrl.calculateBudget();

    // Return the budget
    var budget = budgetCtrl.getBudget();

    // Display the budget on the UI
    UICtrl.displayBudget(budget);
  }

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input, newItem;

    // Get the input data from the form
    input = UICtrl.getInput();

    if (input.description !== '' && !isNaN(input.value) && input.value > 0) {
      // Create a new object with the data
      newItem = budgetCtrl.addItem(input.type, input.description, input.value);

      // Add new item to the UI
      UICtrl.addListItem(newItem, input.type);

      // Clear the fields
      UICtrl.clearFields();

      // Calculate and update budget
      updateBudget();
    }
  }

  var ctrlDeleteItem = function(event) {
    var itemID, splitID, type, ID;

    itemID = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;

    if (itemID) {
      splitID = itemID.split('-');
      type = splitID[0];
      ID = parseInt(splitID[1]);

      // Delete item from the data structure
      budgetCtrl.deleteItem(type, ID);

      // Delete item from the UI
      UICtrl.deleteListItem(itemID);

      // Update and show the new budget
      updateBudget();
    }
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log('The application has started.');
      setupEventListeners();
      UICtrl.displayBudget({
        budget: 0,
        totalInc: 0,
        totalExp: 0,
        percentage: -1
      });
    }
  }

})(budgetController, UIController);

controller.init();
```

```css
/**********************************************
*** GENERAL
**********************************************/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #555;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.red {
  color: #FF5049 !important;
}

.red-focus:focus {
  border: 1px solid #FF5049 !important;
}


/**********************************************
*** TOP PART
**********************************************/

.top {
  height: 40vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)), url(back.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.budget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.budget__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.budget__value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.budget__income,
.budget__expenses {
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.budget__income {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #28B9B5;
}

.budget__expenses {
  background-color: #FF5049;
}

.budget__income--text,
.budget__expenses--text {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.budget__income--value,
.budget__expenses--value {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.budget__income--percentage,
.budget__expenses--percentage {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.budget__expenses--percentage {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/**********************************************
*** BOTTOM PART
**********************************************/


/***** FORM *****/

.add {
  padding: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.add__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.add__type {
  width: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description,
.add__value {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
}

.add__description {
  width: 400px;
}

.add__value {
  width: 100px;
}

.add__btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #28B9B5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.add__btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.add__type:focus,
.add__description:focus,
.add__value:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #28B9B5;
}

.add__btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/***** LISTS *****/

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.income {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.expenses {
  float: left;
  width: 475px;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.icome__title {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses__title {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item {
  padding: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.item__description {
  float: left;
}

.item__value {
  float: left;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.item__percentage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  font-size: 11px;
  background-color: #FFDAD9;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.income .item__value,
.income .item__delete--btn {
  color: #28B9B5;
}

.expenses .item__value,
.expenses .item__percentage,
.expenses .item__delete--btn {
  color: #FF5049;
}

.item__delete {
  float: left;
}

.item__delete--btn {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  display: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.item__delete--btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.item:hover .item__delete--btn {
  display: block;
}

.item:hover .item__value {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.item:hover .item__percentage {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.unpaid {
  background-color: #FFDAD9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FF5049;
}

.unpaid .item__percentage {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.unpaid:hover .item__description {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Budgety</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="top">
    <div class="budget">
      <div class="budget__title">
        Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
      </div>

      <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>

      <div class="budget__income clearfix">
        <div class="budget__income--text">Income</div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="budget__income--value">+ 4,300.00</div>
          <div class="budget__income--percentage">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="budget__expenses clearfix">
        <div class="budget__expenses--text">Expenses</div>
        <div class="right clearfix">
          <div class="budget__expenses--value">- 1,954.36</div>
          <div class="budget__expenses--percentage">45%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="add">
      <div class="add__container">
        <select class="add__type">
          <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
          <option value="exp">-</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
        <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
        <button class="add__btn"><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-outline"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="income">
        <h2 class="icome__title">Income</h2>

        <div class="income__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Salary</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 2,100.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="income-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Sold car</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">+ 1,500.00</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="expenses">
        <h2 class="expenses__title">Expenses</h2>

        <div class="expenses__list">

          <!--
                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-0">
                            <div class="item__description">Apartment rent</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 900.00</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">21%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item clearfix" id="expense-1">
                            <div class="item__description">Grocery shopping</div>
                            <div class="right clearfix">
                                <div class="item__value">- 435.28</div>
                                <div class="item__percentage">10%</div>
                                <div class="item__delete">
                                    <button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use a title that's more descriptive of the specific problem. Everyone is asking for help fixing bugs.

Comment: When you say "delete the last item", do you mean item number 5 when there are 5 items, or do you mean delete the item when there's only one item left?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `calculateTotal()`, which you didn't post. It apparently doesn't work when there are no items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you assign to `data.totals[type] = sum;` inside the `forEach` loop in `calculateTotal()`. If there are no items in the array, the loop never runs, so you never do the assignment.

You don't need to do that assignment each time through the loop, just once after the loop is done calculating the total. So it should be

```
  var calculateTotal = function(type) {
    var sum = 0;

    data.allItems[type].forEach(function(cur) {
      sum += cur.value;
    })
    data.totals[type] = sum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculateTotal = function (type) {
var sum = 0;

data.allItems[type].forEach(function (cur) {
  sum += cur.value;
  data.totals[type] = sum;
}); };
```

if the data.allItems doesn't have any value then the total not getting updated.

You have to check if the allItems have 0 then update the totals as 0